# Solr query multiple collections

Tags: solr, lucene, ranking

I have multiple collections with different fields in the schema, I would like to perform a search across multiple collections and perform default rank for results across all the collections .

Example - I have a document with ‘mustang’ word occurring 3 times in collection A and also 2 times in Collection B , then I would like the results to show both the documents with the document from collection A first and document from collection B as second result.

Answer (score 3):

Scoring doesn't *only* take the number of occurrences into factor, so by default it'll also depend on the number of documents containing that term in the collection as well. If we're talking about a single term, you can sort by the `tf` function or something like that - for more complex queries, using collection wide term frequencies may be the only option (but may be costly).

To create one common collection that queries both, [use the CREATEALIAS](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-createalias) command in the Collections API. The `collections` parameter takes a comma separated list of collections that is represented by the alias, allowing you to query both A and B through the alias C.

Comment: Thanks , would the results follow the default scoring even when I query multiple collections ?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. My guess is that it's internally implemented just in the same way a inter node communication in a single collection.

Comment: @ChiragShah Please do not spam my answers with other answers for getting attention to them.